# How do we generalize from a scalar (one dimensional) equation is transformed into a vector (multidimensional) equation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, vectors

I was reading about Work-Energy theorem recently and they first *derived* it for a constant force. So, they wanted to use the equations of motion which they derived for one dimensional constant acceleration motion. Specifically, they used this equation in scalar form $$ v^2=u^2+2as$$
Now, what they say is that we can generalize the above equation in 3 dimensions by explicitly employing vectors and the generalized equation is $$\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u} + 2 \mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{s} $$
(Note: Here the symbols have their usual meanings)

Now what I wonder is that how this vector generalization is made. When I looked at it more carefully I noticed that only the scalar product can yield us an angle independent relation when the two vector, whose scalar product is calculated, are pointing in the same direction, as evident. But still this argument looks weak enough as it does not shows us hoe the equations are generalized.

What I feel is that the book must be a bit misleading in the aspect that the scalar equation is used to get a generalized vector equation, but, according to me, it must be opposite, and the vector equation must have been used to derive the scalar equation as a special case. But the problem is that I'm not yet familiar with vector calculus and all that stuff, and only understand the physical aspects of vectors.

I want you to help me in this, first by confirming that whether the book is correct when saying that scalar (what I mean by scalar is one dimensional without explicitly using vectors) equation is generalized into vector one, or is it the other way round.Secondly, I want to know that how can we perform such generalization wherein a scalar (one dimensional) equation is transformed into a vector (multidimensional) equation, as this technique could be helpful further in physics to me.

Comment: Reading where ?

Comment: I was reading my high school physics textbook...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case the result can be had by simply working each of the coordinate directions as you did for the one dimensional case and them summing the results
\begin{align}
v_x^2 &= u_x^2 + 2 a_x s_x \tag{1}\\
v_y^2 &= u_y^2 + 2 a_y s_y \tag{2}\\
v_z^2 &= u_z^2 + 2 a_z s_z \tag{3} \;,
\end{align}
then simply summing equations (1)-(3) we get
\begin{align}
\left(v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2\right) 
&= \left(u_x^2 + u_y^2 + u_z^2\right) + 2 \left(a_x s_x + a_y s_y + a_z s_z\right) \tag{4} \;.
\end{align}

Line (4) can be seen to be equivalent to the form with the dot products by inspection.

As to how it is done in  (heh!) general, well you need to get used to looking for the deeper structure so that you can guess how to proceed in showing that the generalization is valid. Cases as easy as this are not uncommon in simple mechanics, but the deeper you go the more subtle things become. Developing a deep mathematical toolbox is to your advantage.